# Indefinite Integral - How to do questions with square roots?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

> $$\int \frac{dx}{x^4 \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}}$$

In the above question, my first step would be to try and get out of the square root, so I would take  $ t^2 = a^2 + x^2 $. But that gets me nowhere. How would you solve this, and if you are going to take a substitution what is the logic behind that substitution?

Comment: The purpose or logic behind using trig or hyperbolic identites is to dissolve the square root, so that for example an integral involving $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ will be simplified using $x=\sin \theta$ etc. etc...

Comment: The more you work on this, the more obvious it becomes, but when you see integrals with square roots of squared terms (particularly in the denominator), that almost always suggests you should start by looking at trig identities for a potentially useful substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

substitute $x=a\tan { \theta  } ,dx=\frac { a\,d\theta  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }$
 so

> $$\\ \\ \\ \int  \frac { dx }{ x^{ 4 }\sqrt { a^{ 2 }+x^{ 2 } }  } =\int  \frac { a\,d\theta  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } { \left( a\tan { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ 4 }\sqrt { a^{ 2 }+{ a }^{ 2 }\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \int { \frac { \cos ^{ 3 }{ \theta  } }{ \sin ^{ 4 }{ \theta  }  }  } \, d\theta  =\\ \\ =\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \int { \frac { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }{ \sin ^{ 4 }{ \theta  }  } d\sin { \theta  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \left[ \int { \frac { d\sin { \theta  }  }{ \sin ^{ 4 }{ \theta  }  }  } -\int { \frac { d\sin { \theta  }  }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \left[ -\frac { 1 }{ 3\sin ^{ 3 }{ \theta  }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sin { \theta  }  }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \left[ -\frac { 1 }{ 3\sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( \arctan { \frac { x }{ a }  }  \right)  }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sin { \left( \arctan { \frac { x }{ a }  }  \right)  }  }  \right] +C\\   $$

Comment: What gave you the hint that this substitution might be the correct way to go?

Comment: Through inspection of the standard trig identities, simply compare the identity to the root. In this case, we can either use the identity $ 1 + tan^2x = sec^2x $ or $ 1 + cot^2x = cosec^2x $.

Comment: @Battini Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{a^4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{a^5}$ ?

Comment: @BrahmnoorSingh,i susbected that it might be correct way)

Comment: @Curious,sure you are right,thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was particularly stuck between the decision - whether to take an algebraic substitution (as indicated in my question) or a trigonometric one. But I think I understand it better now. @Curious

Answer (score 5):

Hint...try substituting $$x=a\sinh \theta$$ and using standard hyperbolic identities and derivatives

Answer (score 3):

You can use trigonometric functions. Substitute $x=a*tan(u)$ and $dx=a*\frac{du}{{cos}^{2}u}$ this gives:

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x^4 \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} =\int \dfrac{du}{a^4\cos(u){\tan}^{4}(u)}$$

Working further on the solution of Battani and by simplifying:

$${ \sin{ \left( \arctan { \frac { x }{ a }  }  \right)  }  }=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$

This gives:

$$\frac { 1 }{ { a }^{ 4 } } \left[ -\frac { 1 }{ 3\sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( \arctan { \frac { x }{ a }  }  \right)  }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sin { \left( \arctan { \frac { x }{ a }  }  \right)  }  }  \right] +C\\=\frac{1}{a^4}\left[ -\frac{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}{3x^3}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{x}\right]$$

Simplifying further:

$$\frac{1}{a^4}\left[ -\frac{(3x^2-{x^2+a^2})\sqrt{x^2+a^2})}{3x^3}\right]=$$

$$-\frac{(2x^2+a^2)\sqrt{x^2+a^2})}{3a^4x^3}$$

Comment: What gave you the hint that this substitution might be the correct way to go?

Comment: @BrahmnoorSingh this is the reference I use for personal use (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-4-techniques-of-integration/part-a-trigonometric-powers-trigonometric-substitution-and-completing-the-square/session-72-trig-substitution/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses72c.pdf); however I can't properly explain why so.